# Include Link with Parameters from a partial view

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

In MVC 3, I load a partial view into a div after submitting a GET request. Sine this is loaded into the div, the link to view isn't contained in the address bar.

How can I include a link in that partial view so it can be accessed directly that includes all of the passed parameters?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you're wanting a link directly to the partial view? Does it have to load the page the partial view is referenced from?

Comment: @BuildStarted: Right, right now I am asking for a link that would directly to the partial view. Your second quesiton, that is a bit more involved -- I think I may have backed myself into a corner here. I can conditionally make that link a partial view... but I might have a larger design issue I am currently trying to think through.

Comment: Heh, didn't mean to back you into a corner. :) I just wasn't sure exactly how you wanted to show the page. The simplest way would be simply use `Request.Url.ToString()` or something to get the url used to load the partial view and just ViewBag it to the client...but I'm not sure how that will fit with your partial page container.

Comment: @BuildStarted: Basically I have a page that has a bunch of different tabs. Each tab has a different form. These forms submit requests to different controller/view pairs. The results of those is displayed in a div from the original page via ajax. But because of this, I can't think of a good way to display the form page with the related tab and the results from a direct link.

Comment: Ah...well then, you could use the "hash-bang" approach...lemme see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So say your root url is: `http://www.example.com/home/index` you can turn it into `http://www.example.com/home/index#all=your&get=parameters&go=here`

Then in your index view you run a javascript event on page load that looks as the hash and then loads your partialview the same way.

```
$(function() { 
    $.get(window.location.hash.replace("#!", ""), function(data){
        $("#contents").html(data);
    });
});
```

something like that, if you're using jquery.

Comment: Does your `get` method use ajax to populate the div?

Comment: Yes, so if the Page with the form were `/home/index`. one of those forms might submit a get to `/graph_it?foo=bar` and load the results in a div. Another form that would also be in `/home/index` might submit to `/alternate_graphit?foo_bar`

Comment: so a simple example would be `/home/index#!/graph_it?foo=bar`